# ZK using button width 100% in hlayout

Tags: button, width, zk

I have the following code that I am trying to set button width=100%  in hlayout. But it does not set. z-hlayout-inner   sets  `.z-hlayout-inner { display: inline-block;}`and this does not allow to make button width hole div. If I remove it on firebug my button covers hole div.

```
<grid>
<columns> 

  <column />
<column/>
</columns>

    <rows>  

<row>
                    <hlayout>

                            <button
                                label="ASD" width="100%"
                                forward="onClick=onOK">
                            </button>

                        </hlayout>
                        <hlayout  >

                            <button
                                label="FGH"
                                width="100%" forward="onClick=onMainMenu">
                            </button>

                        </hlayout>
                    </row>

                </rows>
            </grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute hflex="1" instead of the attribute width="100%"

For example,

```
<button
     label="ASD" hflex="1"
     forward="onClick=onOK">
```

For more details, please refer to [this tutorial](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Hflex_and_Vflex)